# Video tag not working with rails on Safari

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, video

I have a video tag that works in both Chrome and Firefox but not with Safari. Here is my tag

On html:

```
<%= video_tag("working.mp4", class:"video", autoplay: :autoplay, loop: :loop, mute: :mute, poster: "working.jpeg") %>
```

On css:

```
.video {
position: absolute;
top: 50%; left: 50%;
width:100%;
height: 870px;
z-index:1;
object-fit: cover;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
display:block !important;
```

}

The video currently lives in "assets/video/working.mp4"

Answer (score 0):

Try this(if it's not a mime type issue):

```
<video loop autoplay controls="true" width='100%' height='100%' src='//some_video.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>
```

---

What’s the proper MIME type? You’ve already seen it; it’s part of the value of the type attribute on a  element. But setting the type attribute in your HTML markup is not sufficient. You also need to ensure that your web server includes the proper MIME type in the Content-Type HTTP header.

If you’re using the Apache web server or some derivative of Apache, you can use an AddType directive in your site-wide httpd.conf or in an .htaccess file in the directory where you store your video files. (If you use some other web server, consult your server’s documentation on how to set the Content-Type HTTP header for specific file types.)

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

The first line is for videos in an Ogg container. The second line is for videos in an MPEG-4 container. The third is for WebM. Set it once and forget it. If you forget to set it, your videos will fail to play in some browsers, even though you included the MIME type in the type attribute in your HTML markup.

[Source](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#video-mime-types)

Comment: Thanks for helping. Nope, it says "Video Format or MIME type is not supported"

Comment: Just updated the answer. Hopefully, this will solve the issue.

Comment: This is what I added on my application.rb                           : request.content_type == "video/ogg .ogv"
request.content_type == "video/mp4 .mp4"
 request.content_type == "video/webm .webm".      Don't know if this is what you referring to, but doesn't work.

Comment: "This is what I did: - "   I don't get it.

Comment: Could you add the code in a fiddle(https://jsfiddle.net) so that I can check it in chrome and then in Safari?

Comment: Have created it. You can find it here https://jsfiddle.net/kalaivendran/pL0s330s/

Comment: When you say src="working.mp4"you're telling Rails to look for that file from the current route (you're probably on localhost:3000/admin if you're trying it on a local server, so it's looking in localhost:3000/admin/working.mp4).

You could try giving it the route from the home of your app like so: src="/assets/video/working.mp4"


Let me know if it works so that I can edit the answer for others.

Comment: The video_tag on Rails don't require such route, as "working.mp4" which lives in my assets/video works just fine. Again, my video is playing on both Firefox and Chrome at the moment, but not just Safari.

Comment: Just found this answer for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857262/html5-video-is-not-working-in-my-rails-3-app

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd be happy if you'll let me know about your problem fixes or not. :)

Comment: Hi Rahul, unfortunately it still doesn't work in Safari. After adding "controls: true", I can see the video is loading, but that's all it does; it doesn't play.

Comment: Before you give the actual link(if you're planning to  show), try this:

<%= video_tag(["video/trailer_test.mp4"], :size => "320x240", :controls => true) %>

I don't know if I can help you on this anymore without seeing the actual  page where the issue is occurring. Is it possible for you to show it?

Comment: <%= video_tag(["video/trailer_test.mp4"], :size => "320x240", :controls => true) %> again works on Chrome, Firefox, and even my Android phone, but again not Safari. Nvm, thanks a lot. You've been very helpful.